# Octave (GUI): Clear all variables of the work environment in one go

Tags: octave, octave-gui

GNU Octave, Version 6.1.0, using the GUI:

Is there a way to clear all variables that are listed in the work environment without restarting Octave and without clicking and clearing every single variable?

This is needed for a cold start when switching to a new task, when you still want to keep opened the already opened files.

Comment: Just type `clear`.

Comment: `Edit->Clear Workspace` in the menus should work as well.

Comment: Sorry for this too easy question. I only thought to find such a command when I just right-clicked inside the workspace. Obviously not my day.

Comment: There is also a setting in the preferences to re-open tabs from the previous session when you close the GUI and open it again. See `Edit` -> `Preferences` -> `Editor` -> `File-Handling` -> `Restore Editor Tabs from previous session on startup or when editor is shown again after closing`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from the helpful comments, here are the ways to choose from:

1. Type "clear" in the editor.
2. `Edit->Clear Workspace` in the menu.
3. Not recommended of course, but possible: you could also just close the GUI and open it again. *Then, you should at best use the setting to re-open tabs from the previous session when you close the GUI and open it again. See `Edit -> Preferences -> Editor -> File-Handling -> Restore Editor Tabs from previous session on startup or when editor is shown again after closing`*